# E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement and Error: ServiceIntent not found

Tags: android

I am doing a project of simple login app where i have to retrieve the user data from firebase but it shows an error in the logcat.
I have provided my manifest file below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.javapapers.android.androidflashlight.accesscontrolapp">
   <uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".PasswordActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Please help me to correct the code.